# Pygame collision detection while accelerating

Tags: pygame

I am creating a 2D game. I implemented a physics engine in the game so when the player jumps  his arc follows the path given his velocity and the gravity in the game. When the player is falling its distance fallen will continue to get larger and larger because it has acceleration.

How do I know if the player collides with something in its path if the new location puts the player on the other side of the object?

I could use a loop and test every point along the players path. Is this the only way to do it? Is there a more elegant algorithm or pygame solution?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to add an invisible tail opposite to your velocity vector long enough to compensate for large distances travelled between frames.

Answer (score 2):

Pygame itself will not be able to help you I fear. It has some apis for helping you determine if rectangles intersect, but as you've discovered, if an entity is traveling fast enough, they could be on one side of the ground on one update, and on the next update be clear on the other side. This is sometimes referred to as "tunneling".

The simplest way to fix this: don't let your entities travel fast enough to move through the ground (or other entity). You can apply a "terminal velocity" to your falling entity, or increase the frequency of your collision detection.

There are more complicated algorithms to solve this, commonly referred to as "continuous collision algorithms", but these are more complicated. There's a plethora of information available online for these algorithms, so I'll leave that up to you to research if you wish.